# Creating a Firebird DB on a network drive that has a password

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I installed Firebird on a Network drive but cant create a new DB. The network drive has a password and I'm not sure if it makes a difference. I get a sqlstate = 08006 error. Any tips for setting up a Firebird database on a Network drive would be helpful. The line I'm using to create the database is:

```
`CREATE DATABASE 'testDB.gdb' USER 'sysdba' PASSWORD 'masterkey';`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebird specifically does not allow creating a database on a network drive, the database has no need to be on one as access is achieved via the Firebird process on the hosting computer not directly to the database file